# What is wrong with my JCarousel Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am trying to implement [Sorgalla jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) to my website, but I can't seem to get it to work, even though to my knowledge, I have done everything as instructions say.

To help myself think and to simplify the situation, I even created a fiddle with just basic functions, and even that doesn't work!

http://jsfiddle.net/b2cwv/1/

Any suggestions what might be wrong with this? It's simplified from what I have in the website, but the code is basically the same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
            list: '.jcarousel-list',
            items: '.jcarousel-item',
            rtl: true,
            center: true,
            animation: 'slow'
            scroll: '+=1'
            wrap: 'both'
        });   
    });

    $('.jcarousel-prev').click(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '-=1');
    });

    $('.jcarousel-next').click(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '+=1');
    });
});
```

It simply just doesn't **fire**.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: there are a few syntax errors http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L6hjB/1/

Comment: add comma after every configuration like animation, scroll as of now i can think of this, looking for more

Comment: Oh, right, the commas somehow slipped out from SO version, but they're there. No errors in console either. The only "error" at all anywhere is by RubyMine when hovered over jcarousel() function: `Unresolved function or method jcarousel()`. That would suggest jquery.jcarousel.js isn't loaded, but it loads from the same place as other successful jquery code. And even on fiddle it is definitely  loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the comma after all the configuration

```
animation: slow
```

Fix the css list width

```
width: 2em
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/b2cwv/2/

Its working now

Comment: Interestingly enough, it seemed to be exactly the width that was the problem, even though the [installation manual](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/installation.html) specifially suggested 20000em. Even so, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, there was one more typo error, there was extra comma ' at end "wrap'". Please upvote if you find answer useful as it help others and my reputation ;)